# jQuery 3 gives wrong answer for multiple attribute find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a construct that works fine on jQuery 1.4.3 but not for jQuery 3.1.1.  In my page I've a number of INPUT fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="docNo" oninput="setIgnoreDateRange();" data-auto-select-ignoredate="true">
```

The "data-auto-select-ignoredate" attribute is used by setIgnoreDateRange() to toggle a checkbox elsewhere on the form.

In that function I ask how many of these tagged INPUT fields have content:

```
$("form[name='salesOrderSearchForm']").find('[data-auto-select-ignoredate="true"][value!=""]').length
```

In my web page with jQuery 1.4.3 I get an answer depending on how many fields have value.  If there are six fields in all, and one has a value in it, I get a length of 1.

In my web page with jQuery 3.1.1 I get a simple count of the number of the fields on the form, as though the `[value!=""]` weren't even there.  If there are six fields in all, and one has a value in it, I get a length of six.

Has something changed in the formulation of multiple-attribute searches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more recent jQuery versions, you can select `input`s by their `value` attribute, but not by the actual JavaScript `.value` property.

Right now you will have to use filtering. Here is how to do it:

### ES6

```
let ignoringInputs = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="salesOrderSearchForm"] input[data-auto-select-ignoredate="true"]');
ignoringInputs = [...ignoringInputs].filter((element) => element.value !== '');

console.log(ignoringInputs.length);
```

- `[...ignoringInputs]` is so called [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator),
- `(parameter) => function` is so called [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

### jQuery

I haven't used jQuery in a while, but it **may** be something like:

```
var ignoringInputs = $('form[name="salesOrderSearchForm"] input[data-auto-select-ignoredate="true"]');
ignoringInputs = ignoringInputs.filter(function () {
    return $(this).val() !== '';
}

console.log(ignoringInputs.length);
```

### Working example (ES6)

```js
document.getElementById('checkButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let ignoringInputs = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="salesOrderSearchForm"] input[data-auto-select-ignoredate="true"]');
  ignoringInputs = [...ignoringInputs].filter((element) => element.value !== '');
  
  console.log(ignoringInputs.length);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { /* Only for output console */
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form name="salesOrderSearchForm">
  <input type="text" name="docNo" data-auto-select-ignoredate="true">
  <input type="text" name="docNo" data-auto-select-ignoredate="true">
  <input type="text" name="docNo" data-auto-select-ignoredate="true">
  <input type="text" name="docNo" data-auto-select-ignoredate="true">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Check" id="checkButton"/>
```

Comment: In your jQuery, it would be `this.value !== ''` or `$(this).val() !== ''`.

Comment: Corrected and +1

Comment: The command  $("form[name='salesOrderSearchForm']").find('[data-auto-select-ignoredate="true"]').filter(function() {return  $(this).val() != '';}).length;  does it for me.